# Calculating bits of RAM

Tags: operating-systems

Consider I have 30-bit RAM to calculate its size: 2^30 = 1073741824 / 10^9 = 1GB

What if I had for example 512 MB RAM is there formula to convert it to `n-bit` ? this is might be noob question but I'm not good with math :/

Comment: Number of Bytes*8? ;) put attention to the prefix for k M G T or ki... Gi...

Comment: No I want to convert it to n-bit just like the example in first line

Comment: Your first-line calculation is wrong: the result is ~1 Gigabit (1G**b**) or ~128 Megabytes (128M**B**).

Comment: @AFH I think the OP meant that one gigabyte of RAM can be addressed by a 30-bit pointer, assuming that each RAM location is a byte.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're looking for a [**logarithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), a base-two logarithm specifically. Logarithms do the opposite of exponentiation, so if b<sup>x</sup> = y, then x = log<sub>b</sub> y. 2<sup>4</sup> = 16, so log<sub>2</sub> 16 = 4.

First, you'll need to figure out how many bytes you have. If your number is in kilobytes, multiply by 2<sup>10</sup>. For megabytes, 2<sup>20</sup>, for gigabytes 2<sup>30</sup>, et cetera. As you can see, I'm using the powers-of-1024 definitions of these units rather the powers-of-1000 definitions, so one kilobyte here is 1024 bytes. The unambiguous name for 1024 bytes is [kibibyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix). Anyway, 512 MB is equal to 512 • 2<sup>20</sup> = 536870912 bytes.

Now you'll need a scientific calculator. I like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/), which lets you do base-two logarithms with the `log2` function. `log2(536870912)` [produces](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(536870912)) 29, which makes sense, considering that 512 MB is half of 1 GB, so it takes one less power of two. You can use pretty much any operator imaginable in a Wolfram Alpha expression, so `log2(512 * 10^20)` [works too](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(512+*+2%5E20)).

If you get a number with a decimal part, round up. For example, you'd need three bits to address five bytes of RAM, though `log2(5)` is roughly 2.32.

Comment: FYI, [Google also evaluates `log2(536870912)` just fine](https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=log2(536870912)).

Comment: Feels like `log(536870912) / log(2)` could be mentioned in case `log2()` is unavailable.

Comment: Although it is covered in the linked Wikipedia article, it would improve this answer to add a few words about *why* you're looking for a logarithm. That way, it can be understood not as this strange mathematical concept, but simply as the inverse operation to exponentiation, which the asker already has a grasp on.

Comment: you can use powershell `[math]::Log(536870912, 2)`. Or `echo "l(536870912)/l(2)" | bc -l` or `python -c  'import math; print math.log(536870912, 2)'`

Answer (score 4):

Additionally to what Ben said, I recommend first doing the logarithm of your number without units

```
log₂512 = 9
```

And then take units into consideration: sum 10 for kibibytes, 20 for mebibytes, 30 for gibibytes, ...

```
9 + 20 = 29
```

And that's it. No need to calculate huge numbers. That's because logarithms have the following properties:

```
logₙ(a × b) = logₙ(a) +  logₙ(b)
logₙ(aᵇ) = b × logₙ(a)
```

Therefore,

```
log₂(512 × 2²⁰) = log₂(512) + 20
```

However, if you already know `log₂(1 GiB) = 30`,

```
log₂(512 MiB) = log₂(1 GiB / 2) = log₂(1 GiB) - log₂(2) = 30 - 1 = 29
```